# How many different 8 character passwords can be created?

Tags: combinatorics

The question is: Suppose that a web password is always 8 characters long and it always comprises two upper case letters, one digit, and 5 lower case letters. How many different passwords can be created that follow these rules?

The solution given looks wrong to me:

$${8 \choose 2}\times {6 \choose 1} \times 26 \times 26 \times 10 \times 26^5$$

I am confused about the usage of $8\choose 2$, apparently this is supposed to be the number of places the two upper case letters can go, shouldn't this just be $8 \times 7$ and then to remove duplicates like `A**A****` we explicitly subtract values like this?

Comment: Let's label every position in the password as $p_1,...,p_8$. The number $\binom{8}{2}$ just tells us in how many way we can choose a set $\{p_i, p_j\}$ where $i \neq j$. In other words, $\binom{8}{2}$ counts how many pairs (p_i, p_j) with $i \neq j$ we can choose with no regard of the order.

Comment: @Student2271 but why do we disregard the order? Shouldn't it matter, since password starting with `AB` is not the same as password starting with `BA`

Comment: The $8\times 7$ gives you 2 places $a$ and $b$. $a$ has $26$ choices, and so does $b$. You're double counting since when you interchange $a,b$ and the two choices, you get the same overall case, but your formula counts them as different.

Comment: ${8 \choose 2}$ describes only positions, $26\cdot 26$ includes order

Comment: To clarify my first comment : suppose $8\times 7$ lands you places 1 and 3. You put an A on 1 and B on 3. Next time, $8 \times 7$ lands you $3$ and $1$, you put B on 3 and A on 1. Same thing. But $\binom{8}{2}$ gives you the _unordered pair_ $(1,3)$ where the $26 \times 26$ will give you all possible cases.

Comment: For every positions like `U**U****` there are 26 cases for first Upper case letter and 26 cases for second Upper case letter

Comment: Suppose it was simply a 2-letter password using Upper Case Letters.  Would you say $2\times 1 \times 26\times 26=1352$ or ${2 \choose 2}\times 26\times 26=676$?

Comment: @DS This makes sense, but why is it with places we do ignore the order, is it because the set of letters is same for both places? If the set were different would $8 \times 7$ be correct? if I am making some sense

Comment: Consider a conveyor belt. You pick up a pair of boxes$(p_i,p_j)$ such that $i\neq j$, and pass it on the belt. Above the belt are two machines that drop a capital letter into the boxes, exactly when $p_i$ is below the first and $p_j$ is below the second. Does it make sense to send the pair $(p_j,p_i)$ on the belt, when there is a chance that the machines drop the letter which the other dropped last time?

Comment: And when one machine drops capitals and the other lowecases, well then you need to send both $(p_i,p_j)$ and $(p_j,p_i)$

Comment: Okay, it now makes a LOT more sense. Took a lot of internalizing for me to get it. Yes, it is a simple idea on paper, but I really wanted to see why, thanks @DS, Henry and Ivan :)))))